# How can a user reset permissions settings after declining the JS Geolocation request? (iOS Safari)

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, w3c-geolocation

After a request is to made for the user's geolocation, using either `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` or `watchPosition`, the user is shown a native permission dialog.

If the user selects "*Don't Allow*" to the request to share their location, the API correctly responds with a `PERMISSION_DENIED` code.

However, if the user were to have pressed that by accident, and wishes to clear existing settings, what steps should they follow to do so?

---

This seems absurd enough to warrant a question.

- With Android Chrome; the user can simply press the information icon and adjust the permission.
- On iOS Safari, there does not appear to be a way beyond clearing all of Safari's cache and settings; thereby closing the site they were on in the first place.

Comment: i have the same issue, today has a new Web API to manage the permissions but that is a experimental yet

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API

Comment: That is true there is a new api to manage the permissions on web Permissions API, with querying requesting, revoking the permissions given for apis needs user consent like geolocation, notifications, microphone, camera etc. But its request method yet to be implemented by browsers, and the apis should be registered to be managed by it.